# Android Cannot Instantiate the type Request

Tags: android, android-intent, request, android-download-manager

I have the following code for downloading a file using a download service.
Apparently there are no errors.But eclipse is showing the error "Cannot instantiate type Request" near `Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(downUrl));`

I couldn't find any issue with my code.So why is it happening.How to fix it?
Since my code has syntax highlighting issues in stackoverflow please [find it here](http://pastebin.com/jsg5s0hp)

Comment: import org.omg.CORBA.Request; That is your import for Request. I don't think that's the class you really intended to use?

Comment: so which class should i use ?

Comment: I posted an answer with more info. If you're trying to use Android's DownloadManager, then use the Request from that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your import from import `org.omg.CORBA.Request;` to import `android.app.DownloadManager.Request;`

Here's a nice complete example of DownloadManager too, in case it helps: http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/.